# facebook commet post from my site using .net 

Tags: facebook

I have a site that allows a user to login using their facebook login id through a .net system. When the user posts a comment in my site, I want it to automatically post the comment on their facebook wall too. How can I do this using .net?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[Stream.publish](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish/)** method to post to user' wall.